# None spatial and spatial GeoJSON how to display data in popup and map Leaflet

Tags: javascript, join, leaflet

I have a polygon (zip codes) GeoJSON file in a leaflet map that I want to display data from another GeoJSON/JSON or CSV file that does not have any spatial coordinates. There is an zipcode ID that links to each other. The polygon file with zip codes is pretty much intact over time but the other tables changes regularly. I need a way to "join" this files "on the go" when opening the Leaflet map and addTo(map) for showing the table data for each polygon (fillcolor and-or popups)

The spatial GeoJSON polygon file looks as follow:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ZIPCODE":123456,"date":"2021-01-01","SID":875562 },"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":...
```

Example of non spatial table data

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ZIP_ID":123456,"REGION":"WEST","amount":4,"userID":562,"name":"Susan Anderson"},"geometry":null}
```

I use the following to import the polygonfile and style into Leaflet, but how to get the values from the table data to display on the map? Colors based on the amount and get the popup to display data both from zip code polygon as well as the table data?

```
fetch("../geo/zipcode_2021.geojson", {
method: "Get"
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json =>{

 var vectorGrid_zip =  L.vectorGrid.slicer(json, {
                  maxZoom: 20,
                  zIndex: 4,
                  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                      sliced: function(properties, zoom){   
                      var amount = properties.amount //values from table data
                      if (amount <= 10 ) {
                      return    {
                        weight: 0.5,
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        color:  'black',
                        fillOpacity: 0,
                        fill: true,
                        }
                    } else if (amount > 10 && amount <= 50) {
                      return {
                        weight: 0.5,
                        fillColor: 'blue',
                        color:  'black',
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        fill: true,
                        }           
                    } else {
                      return {
                        weight: 0.5,
                        fillColor: 'white',
                        color:  'black',
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        fill: true,
                        }                             
                      }     
                     }},
                     interactive: true,
                   })
vectorGrid_zip.on('click', polygonClick);
vectorGrid_zip.addTo(zip_data) //add to LayerGroup
});

        function polygonClick(e) {
        var properties = e.layer.properties;
            L.popup()
            .setContent(
                "<b>Zip Code: </b>" + properties.ZIPCODE + //from polygon
                "<br><b>Amount: </b>" + properties.amount + //from table data
                "<br><b>ID, User: </b>" + properties.userID + ", " + properties.name + //from table data
                "<br><b>Region: </b>" + properties.REGION + //from table data
                "<br>Date: " + '<i>' + properties.date + '</i>' //from polygon
                )
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .openOn(map);
            
            L.DomEvent.stop(e);
    };
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-post from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397646/none-spatial-and-spatial-geojson-how-to-display-data-in-popup-and-map-leaflet

Comment: Sorry but I deleted the question from stackexchange and moved it here as someone else pointed it was wrong forum...

Comment: This sounds more like a general javascript question than a leaflet question.  I would consider 2 approaches - before writing any leaflet code, use javascript to zip the 2 objects together according to where ZIPCODE matches ZIP_ID, then use *that new object* to make your layer.  *Or*, within polygonClick, use e.layer.properties.ZIPCODE, compare against the non-geo data to find where it matches ZIP_ID, then use the resulting data.  If we had a sandbox to play with we could try to experiment for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will have look into zip with javascript, for the polygonClick will not help as I need to colorise polygons based on values as well. The first reaction to this looks to be a bit more advanced than I expected. Was hoping for an "join" table based on values approach, but I guess that is not available as I can't find any from searches